# getGenerationId android for api8

Tags: android

I have List of Bitmaps in android, I want to return the Generation Id,
Its working with getGenerationId() but with API 12 and higher, Is there any way to get it in API 8 ?

```
    Item item = data.get(position);

    int gID  = item.image.getGenerationId();
```

Thank you.

Comment: do you wants to identify the bitmaps form list ..?

Comment: No, the List is full of Bitmaps, I need to return the Generated ID for each Bitmap

Comment: this method is Added in API level 12 so android it will not available with API 8 okay ,my question is :: why you required generated Id of bitmap..?